# testing a class with out activity and services

Tags: android, junit

this is my  actual class I am writing test class below.

```
public class ReadFile {
private Scanner rx, tx;

public void openFile() {
    try {
        rx = new Scanner(new File("/sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/rx_bytes"));
        tx = new Scanner(new File("/sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/tx_bytes"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String readRxFile() {
    String rxData = "";
    while (rx.hasNext()) {
        rxData = rx.next();
    }

    return rxData;
}

public String readTxFile() {
    String txData = "";
    while (tx.hasNext()) {
        txData = tx.next();
    }
    return txData;
}

public void closeFile() {
    rx.close();
    tx.close();
}
}
```

this is test class. to test the read data.

```
public class Testreadrxfile extends TestCase {

public Testreadrxfile() {
    super();
}

protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    try {
        super.setUp();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

ReadFile rf;

public void testappdata() {
   String str1 = rf.readRxFile();
    Assert.assertEquals("14081",str1 );
}

}
```

this is the error I am getting.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
atcom.android.deviceintelligence1.             test.Testreadrxfile.testappdata(Testreadrxfile.java:26)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:529)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1448)
```

this is not activity or service test to use getactivity() or getservice() so what I should do to get out of this error . thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see your code.. `rf` is not initialised..

```
ReadFile rf; // not intialisd

public void testappdata() {
   String str1 = rf.readRxFile(); // equivalent to null.readRxFile();
    Assert.assertEquals("14081",str1 );
}
```

Comment: what I should initialise. its not activity to write rf = getActivity. As what I should initialise rf now.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, rf is not initialised. In this kind of situation first thing to do is attach the debugger on the line you are getting error, and in most cases answer becomes obvious.

**UPDATE**

first your code didn't work because you didn't initialised rx, now your code doesn't work becasue you never called following function. In the function you are initialising your scanner objects. call this function from your readRxFile function and you should be good to go.

```
public void openFile() { 
    try { 
        rx = new Scanner(new File("/sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/rx_bytes")); 
        tx = new Scanner(new File("/sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/tx_bytes")); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
} 

public String readRxFile() { 
    String rxData = ""; 
    while (rx.hasNext()) { //eq. to null.haxNext()
        rxData = rx.next(); 
    } 

    return rxData; 
}
```

Comment: what I should initialise. its not activity to write rf = getActivity. As what I should initialise rf now.

Comment: well ReadFile rf = new ReadFile(); also you need to have an constructor in ReadFile class, public ReadFile() {}

Comment: this is basic concepts, you need to initialize your objects otherwise you'll surely get NullPointerException, which intern means that something is not initialize and pointing towards a 
"Black Hole"